# Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance from server no longer active

Tags: 2013, distributedcache

I have a server, server5, no longer accessible. The problem is that it is still added to the distributed cache, even though it was removed from the farm.

How can I specify what server name I want to be removed when I run Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance. NOTE I have not run the command due to being afraid of removing local box instead of removing box no longer running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the command,

```
 Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

which did remove the local server from the cache. I ended up following a guide and creating a new search topology which was not ideal but was the only way to resolve the issue.

You can follow the guide here, [http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/04/09/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-topology.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+yahoo%2FZfiM+(Team+blog+of+MCS+%40+Middle+East+and+Africa)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2013/04/09/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-topology.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+yahoo%2FZfiM+%28Team+blog+of+MCS+%40+Middle+East+and+Africa%29)

Comment: It would be very helpful to share that command and guide for future readers